# JQuery UI Draggable, Can't drag out of a twitter bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a `droppable` outside of a twitter bootstrap tab.  It's in a parent row (but I don't think that's the issue).  I can't drag my `draggable` outside of the tab to the `droppable`.  The `draggable` is constrained within the tab even after changing the `zIndex`.  If its not the `zIndex` than I have no idea what to persue.

Here's a contrived fiddle of my problem: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/UPG5F/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work anymore. Is there any chance on restoring this? It is useful to the others as well.

Comment: @freejosh - how odd!  I will try and re-engineer the problem.  Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that the drop gets triggered correctly when you ignore the visual of the box being cut off. So, this is just a display issue:

A parent of the draggable box, `.tab-content`, is set to `overflow: auto`, which hides elements outside of its bounds and adds scrollbars. Change it to `overflow: visible` and it works properly.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work anymore. Is there any chance on restoring this? It is useful to the others as well.

Comment: @acudars it looks like the jsfiddle account is gone. I'll paste your comment onto the question so that the OP is notified